# Common/less formal word for "distinctiveness"

Tags: single-word-requests

> The building looks plain. Its only **distinctiveness** is the cat logo.

I'm pretty sure *distinctiveness* is not an everyday word. What's a better alternative?

Comment: distinctive feature?

Comment: *noticeable feature* or *feature of note*

Comment: "The only thing special about it is the 'cat' logo."  "Its only specialty is ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Distinctiveness* is not an unusual word by any means, but you're right that it's not a good fit here. It would be better to write:

> Its only **distinctive feature** is the cat logo.

'Distinctive feature' means approximately the same as 'noticeable characteristic'.

You could also write:

> Its only **distinguishing feature** is the cat logo.

In the context of your question, that would mean 'characteristic that sets it apart from other buildings'.

Answer (score 1):

unique feature? standout feature?

Answer (score 1):

Or perhaps, merely "distinction"?